# How Get Cumulative Sum (with Sum of the Past) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

I work with SQL Server 2008.

In my db I have a table `items` that has this sample data:

```
id     |date      |title    |price
-----------------------------------
1      |20150310  |A        |100   
2      |20150201  |B        |25   
3      |20140812  |C        |225   
4      |20130406  |D        |110   
5      |20150607  |E        |645   
6      |20120410  |F        |450   
7      |20130501  |G        |325   
8      |20150208  |H        |175
```

I want to have a cumulative sum of the `price` column after 20150101 (with sum of the past).

In fact I want the results exactly like this:

```
date      |title        |price    |cum_sum   |before_cum_sum
---------------------------------------------------------------
          |sum of past  |         |         |1110
20150201  |B            |25       |1135     |
20150208  |H            |175      |1310     |
20150310  |A            |100      |1410     |
20150607  |E            |645      |2055     |
```

How get the result like that in SQL Server ?

Comment: What is the destination for this data?  A web page?  An SSRS report?

Comment: @AnnL. this Will be displayed on the datagridview in winforms C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP wants specific output - so I comply:

```
DECLARE @items TABLE ([date] DATETIME, title VARCHAR (100), price MONEY)
INSERT @items VALUES ('20150310','A',100), ('20150201','B',25 ), ('20140812','C',225), ('20130406','D',110),   ('20150607','E',645),   ('20120410','F',450),   ('20130501','G',325),   ('20150208','H',175)
;WITH p_cte AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , RowNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATE)
  FROM
    @items
),
p2_cte AS (
  SELECT
    p_cte.date
  , p_cte.title
  , p_cte.price
  , p_cte.RowNo
  , cum_sum = price
  , before_cum_sum = CONVERT (MONEY, 0)
  FROM
    p_cte
  WHERE p_cte.RowNo = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    cur.date
  , cur.title
  , cur.price
  , cur.RowNo
  , cum_sum = cur.price + prev.cum_sum
  , before_cum_sum = prev.cum_sum
  FROM
    p_cte cur
  INNER JOIN p2_cte prev ON
    prev.RowNo = cur.RowNo - 1
)
SELECT TOP 1
  date = CONVERT (DATETIME, NULL)
, title = 'sum of past'
, price = CONVERT (MONEY, NULL)
, rowno = CONVERT (INT, NULL)
, cum_sum = CONVERT (MONEY, NULL)
, p2_cte.before_cum_sum
FROM p2_cte WHERE date > '20150101'
UNION ALL
SELECT
  *
FROM p2_cte WHERE date > '20150101'
```

Output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: thanks, but you manually set @before variable, Whereas I want the 1100 calculate by sum of past records.
also i want the 1100 value show as a record on Top of Table

Comment: i only set the `@before` manually to match your desired output. the change i did is just getting rid of `@before` usage and remove the date range. as for how it should look like (formatting) - i'll leave that with you to do that on your C# code. shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: ok - i added the mock row for sum of past using `SELECT TOP 1` and `UNION ALL`. should get the output to exactly what you want.

Comment: I use your new codes and all of records displayed like this:
[link](http://s6.picofile.com/file/8188496568/1.png)
but i want the records after 20150101

Comment: don't know how you run it - but the above screenshot is what i got (see edit)

Comment: this is as far as i could help you - i'll leave further modification to your hands. please accept the answer and/or upvote if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

A little bit shorter version:

```
select id, 
       date, 
       title, 
       price,
       (select sum(price) from tbl t2 where t2.id <= t1.id) cum_sum, 
       null before_cum_sum
from tbl t1
where date >= '20150101'

union all

select null, 
       null, 
       'before 2015', 
       null,
       null,
       (select sum(price) where date < '20150101')
```